# Cannot require_relative 'model' - uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

So I scraped data from a website into my `scraper.rb` file, everything is working and fine.

Now I want to build class instances of Table with this data, which I pushed into an array called `@tables_new`. Of course I have to require_relative "table" (my model table) but I always get this error message uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError).

So I googled and of course and already had implemented:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

which is also not helping.

On the other hand could I somehow pass the @tables_new data somewhere else and create Table instances there?

Anyone can help me out with this?

```
code: scraper.rb

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

class PingPongScraper

  def initialize
    @tables_new = []
    @agent = Mechanize.new
  end

  def fetch_pingpong_tables

    num_pages_to_scrape = 1
    # num_pages_to_scrape = 290 // all pages to scrap from
    count = 0
    webcount = 0

    while(num_pages_to_scrape > count)
      page = @agent.get("website{webcount}").parser # took the original website out here :) 

      page.css('.list_item .inner').each do |link|

      @tables_new << {location: link.content.strip.split("\n")[2].strip, description: link.content.strip.split("\n")[1].strip}
      end

      webcount += 30
      count += 1
    end

    @tables_new.each do |table|
      p table
      Table.create!(table)
    end
  end
end
```

```
r = PingPongScraper.new
r.fetch_pingpong_tables
```

Comment: How are you loading Rails environment in your script?

Comment: Hi, I'am not loading the Rails environment in a script, this is a rails app.

https://github.com/Janis4411/rails-table-tennis

Comment: You should load the rails environment then.

Comment: Sorry im pretty new to Rails and coding in general. I dont understand what you mean. This file scraper.rb is inside my rails app. It is a complete functioning web app. I just have problems with the creation of Table instances with my scraped data.

Could you maybe elaborate on your comment?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=load+rails+environment

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well when I was moving from sidekiq and redis to shoryuken and sqs. Like `@D. SM` mentioned in the comment (thanks for the tip), I needed to load the rails environment explicitly. Though I've been working with rails for a while, how to manually load the rails environment in the worker was not immediately clear to me so I'm adding this answer here in case someone else encounters it. I've added the following two lines at the top of my worker, adjusting the path to point to my `environment.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```